# Convert html form fields to pdf using pdfsharp.net - .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp

Want to convert this HTML form to a PDF form using pdfsharp.net
I know how to convert html page to PDF using pdfsharp, but unable to convert `<input type="text" />`

[image]

Comment: PDFsharp cannot convert HTML. You should specify the tool you are using and remove the inappropriate PDFsharp tag.

Comment: It is a free tool for .net, available here http://pdfsharp.net
I am using it to convert HTML to PDF, but unable to convert text fields, as mentioned on question image.

Comment: So the PDFsharp tag is appropriate. Looks like "unclear what you are asking" to me. You convert the text boxes with your own code and in the PDF they will look as you want them to look. Just do it. You show how they look in the browser, but don't explain how you want to show them in the PDF. Explain what you need or this is a candidate for "too broad".